# Почему при вызове моего плагина к двум разным слайдерам срабатывает только второй?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Подскажите пожалуйста почему при вызове моего плагина к двум слайдерам срабатывает только второй слайдер и тот почему с неправильным таймингом. Если вызываю только к одному всё работает правильно. Думаю ошибка где-то в инициализации плагина, но где именно не могу найти.

```js
(function($){
var settings = {
    sliderInterval: 3000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,                               
    course: 1,
    nextBtn: '.nextBtn',
    prevBtn: '.prevBtn',
    stopSlider: false      
};  //объект с настройками 

$.fn.simpleSlider = function(options) {
  settings = $.extend(settings, options); // сливаем настройки которые передал пользователь со своим объектом

   
  return this.each(function(){  


    var thisEl =$(this),
    slider = thisEl.children('div','ul','img'),
    slideWidth = thisEl.width(),
    slider_item = slider.children(),
    slideCount = slider_item.length,
    next = settings.nextBtn,
    prev = settings.prevBtn,   
    course = settings.course,                                         // Направление движения слайдера (1 или -1)
    margin = - slideWidth;                              // Первоначальное смещение слайдов
 

  slider_item.css('width',slideWidth);
  // slider_item.last().clone().prependTo(slider);   // Копия последнего слайда помещается в начало.
  slider_item.eq(0).clone().appendTo(slider);   // Копия первого слайда помещается в конец.  
  // slider.css('margin-left', -slideWidth);         // Контейнер .slider сдвигается влево на ширину одного слайда.
  slider_item = slider.children();
 


  function nextSlide(){                                 // Запускается функция animation(), выполняющая смену слайдов.
    interval = window.setInterval(animate, settings.sliderInterval);
  }



$(window).resize(function() {  
  slideWidth = thisEl.width();
  resized=true;
 }).resize()

  function animate(){
    if (resized) {
    //если поменялись размеры окна слайдера, то пересчитываем отступ слайдеров и меняем их ширину.
    var widthslider=slider_item.width(); //старая ширина слайдеов
    var numslider=parseInt(-margin/widthslider); //номер текущего слайдера
    slider_item.css('width',slideWidth); //меняем ширину слайдеров
    margin = 0 /*-slideWidth * numslider;*/ //считаем смещение слайдеров слева
    slider.css('margin-left', margin); //меняем смещение слайдов слева
    resized=false;
  }
    if (margin==-slideCount*slideWidth/*-slideWidth*/){     // Если слайдер дошел до конца
      slider.css({'marginLeft':0/*-slideWidth*/});           // то блок .slider возвращается в начальное положение
      margin=-slideWidth/*2*/;
    }else if(margin==0 && course==-1){                  // Если слайдер находится в начале и нажата кнопка "назад"
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth*slideCount});// то блок .slider перемещается в конечное положение
      margin=-slideWidth*slideCount+slideWidth;
    }else{                                              // Если условия выше не сработали,
    margin = margin - slideWidth*(course);              // значение margin устанавливается для показа следующего слайда
    }
    slider.animate({'marginLeft':margin},settings.animateTime);  // Блок .slider смещается влево на 1 слайд.
  }
 
  function sliderStop(){

    window.clearInterval(interval);                     // Функция преостанавливающая работу слайдера 
  }
 
  $(settings.prevBtn).click(function() {                               // Нажата кнопка "назад"
    if (slider.is(':animated')) { return false; }       // Если не происходит анимация
    var course2 = course;                               // Временная переменная для хранения значения course
    course = -1;                                        // Устанавливается направление слайдера справа налево
    animate();                                          // Вызов функции animate()
    course = course2 ;                                  // Переменная course принимает первоначальное значение
  });
  $(settings.nextBtn).click(function() {                               // Нажата кнопка "назад"
    if (slider.is(':animated')) { return false; }       // Если не происходит анимация
    var course2 = course;                               // Временная переменная для хранения значения course
    course = 1;                                         // Устанавливается направление слайдера справа налево
    animate();                                          // Вызов функции animate()
    course = course2 ;                                  // Переменная course принимает первоначальное значение
  });
  
  if (settings.stopSlider) {    // триггер для включения выключения данной функции
  slider.add(next).add(prev).hover(function() {        // Если курсор мыши в пределах слайдера
    sliderStop();                                          // Вызывается функция sliderStop() для приостановки работы слайдера
  }, nextSlide);                                        // Когда курсор уходит со слайдера, анимация возобновляется.
 }  
  nextSlide();                                          // Вызов функции nextSlide()

});

};


})(jQuery);


$( document ).ready(function() {


$('.slider_wrapper').simpleSlider({
    stopSlider: true,
    sliderInterval: 3000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,                               
});

$('.sliderReviews_window').simpleSlider({
    stopSlider: true,
    sliderInterval: 2000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,
    nextBtn: '.nextReviews',
    prevBtn: '.prevReviews'                               
});


})
```

```css
.sliderSec{
 background-color: $block_grey;
 margin-top: 120px;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 51px;
 position: relative;
}

.slider_wrapper{
 max-width:1000px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: 100px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 outline:1px solid #cc0000;//del
}

.NextPrev{
 position: relative;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}
.nextBtn,.prevBtn{
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 40px;
 color: $c_blue;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
 display: block;
}
.prevBtn{
 content: '\f104';
 left: 26px;
}
.nextBtn{
  content: '\f105';
  right: 18px;
}

.sliderCitat{
 width: 10000px;
 position: relative;
}
.slider_item{
 width: 1000px; 
 float: left;
 z-index: 0;
}
.slider_item img{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 150px;
 }
.slider_item p{
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: roboto-exampleIt;
  margin-left: 225px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  word-spacing: -2px;
  color: $text_grey;
 }
.slider_item h4{
  font-family: KaushanReg;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 295px;
  margin-top: -10px;
 }
.slider_item h4:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 61px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: $c_red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: -70px;
 }



.slider_reviews{
 background-color: #fff;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 51px;
 position: relative;
}

.sliderReviews_window{
 max-width:1020px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: 80px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 outline:1px solid #cc0000;//del
}

.npReviews{
 position: relative;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.nextReviews,.prevReviews{
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 50px;
 color: #ccc;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
 display: block;
}
.prevReviews{
 content: '\f104';
 left: 26px;
}
.nextReviews{
  content: '\f105';
  right: 18px;
}




.sliderReviews{
 width: 10000px;
 position: relative;
}
.reviews_item{
 width: 1020px; 
 float: left;
 z-index: 0;
 }
.reviews_item img{
  border-radius: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  max-width: 210px;
  max-height: 210px;
 }
.reviews_item p{
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: roboto-exampleIt;
  margin-left: 240px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  word-spacing: -2px;
  color: $text_grey;
 }
.reviews_item h4{
  font-family: KaushanReg;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 310px;
  margin-top: -10px;
 }
.reviews_item h4:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 61px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: $c_red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: -70px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">


<section class="sliderSec">
 <div class="NextPrev">
  <span class="prevBtn"><i class="far fa-angle-left"></i></span>
  <span class="nextBtn"><i class="far fa-angle-right"></i></span>


 <div class="slider_wrapper">
  
  <div class="sliderCitat">

   <div class="slider_item">
    <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="">
    <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
    <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
   </div>
   
   <div class="slider_item">
    <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="">
    <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
    <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
   </div>

   <div class="slider_item">
    <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="">
    <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
    <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
   </div>

   <div class="slider_item">
    <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar6.png" alt="">
    <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
    <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 
</section>

<section class="slider_reviews">
 <div class="npReviews">
  <span class="prevReviews"><i class="far fa-angle-left"></i></span>
  <span class="nextReviews"><i class="far fa-angle-right"></i></span>

 <div class="sliderReviews_window">
  
  <div class="sliderReviews">

   <div class="reviews_item">
    <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="">
    <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
    <h4>Joshua Earle</h4>
   </div>
   
   <div class="reviews_item">
    <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="">
    <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
    <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
   </div>

   <div class="reviews_item">
    <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="">
    <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
    <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 
</section>



</div>
```

Comment: например потому, что ты зачем-то глобальные переменные используешь

Comment: а виной всему `;` вот тут: `var thisEl =$(this);` замени на `,` и все должно заработать

Comment: столько времени убито на пропущенную запятую, спасибо тебе добрый человек

Comment: Не подскажешь, где здесь ошибка ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919555/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%ba