# Почему функция остановки слайдера при наведении не работает если плагин вызван к двум элементам?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Подскажите пожалуйста. При наведении на слайдер он должен останавливаться. Если инициализирую один слайдер всё нормально ,если два и больше ,то остановка при наведении не работает и появляется глюк ускоряющий слайдер. Где тут у меня ошибка в плагине?

```
  function nextSlide(){                                 // Запускается функция animation(), выполняющая смену слайдов.
    interval = window.setInterval(animate, settings.sliderInterval);
  }
   function sliderStop(){                                // Функция преостанавливающая работу слайдера      
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
  slider.add(next).add(prev).hover(function() {        // Если курсор мыши в пределах слайдера
    sliderStop();                                          // Вызывается функция sliderStop() для приостановки работы слайдера
  }, nextSlide);
```

Код

```js
(function($){
var settings = {
    sliderInterval: 3000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,                               
    course: 1,
    stopSlider: false      
};  //объект с настройками 




$.fn.simpleSlider = function(options) {
  settings = $.extend(settings, options); // сливаем настройки которые передал пользователь со своим объектом



  return this.each(function(){  


    var thisEl =$(this),
    slider = thisEl.children('div','ul','img'),
    slideWidth = thisEl.width(),
    slider_item = slider.children(),
    slideCount = slider_item.length,
    next = settings.nextBtn,
    prev = settings.prevBtn,   
    course = settings.course,                                       
    margin = 0;                            

  slider_item.css('width',slideWidth);
  slider_item.eq(0).clone().appendTo(slider);   
  slider_item = slider.children();
 


  function nextSlide(){                                 // Запускается функция animation(), выполняющая смену слайдов.
    interval = window.setInterval(animate, settings.sliderInterval);
  }

  function animate(){
    if (margin==-slideCount*slideWidth){   
      slider.css({'marginLeft':0});          
      margin=-slideWidth/*2*/;
    }else if(margin==0 && course==-1){                
      slider.css({'marginLeft':-slideWidth*slideCount});
      margin=-slideWidth*slideCount+slideWidth;
    }else{                                             
    margin = margin - slideWidth*(course);             
    }
    slider.animate({'marginLeft':margin},settings.animateTime); 
  }
 
   function sliderStop(){                                // Функция преостанавливающая работу слайдера      
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
 

  
  if (settings.stopSlider) {    // триггер для включения выключения данной функции
  slider.add(next).add(prev).hover(function() {        // Если курсор мыши в пределах слайдера
    sliderStop();                                          // Вызывается функция sliderStop() для приостановки работы слайдера
  }, nextSlide);                                        // Когда курсор уходит со слайдера, анимация возобновляется.
 }  


  nextSlide();                                          // Вызов функции nextSlide()


});

};


})(jQuery);


$( document ).ready(function() {


$('.slider_wrapper').simpleSlider({
    stopSlider: true,
    sliderInterval: 3000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,                               
});

$('.sliderReviews_window').simpleSlider({
    stopSlider: false,
    sliderInterval: 3000,                              
    animateTime: 1000,
    nextBtn: '.nextReviews',
    prevBtn: '.prevReviews'                               
});


});
```

```css
    .sliderSec, .slider_reviews{
     background-color: $block_grey;
     margin-top: 120px;
     padding-top: 70px;
     padding-bottom: 51px;
     position: relative;
    }

    .slider_wrapper, .sliderReviews_window{
     max-width:1000px;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-right: 100px;
     margin-left: 100px;
     outline:1px solid #cc0000;//del
    }


   .sliderCitat, .sliderReviews{
     width: 10000px;
     position: relative;
    }
    .slider_item, .reviews_item{
     width: 1000px; 
     float: left;
     z-index: 0;
    }
    .slider_item img, .reviews_item img{
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
      width: 150px;
     }
    .slider_item p, .reviews_item p{
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: roboto-exampleIt;
      margin-left: 225px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      word-spacing: -2px;
      color: $text_grey;
     }
    .slider_item h4, .reviews_item h4{
      font-family: KaushanReg;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 400;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 295px;
      margin-top: -10px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">


<section class="sliderSec">

<div class="slider_wrapper">
 
 <div class="sliderCitat">

  <div class="slider_item">
   <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="">
   <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
   <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider_item">
   <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="">
   <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
   <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_item">
   <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="">
   <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
   <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_item">
   <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar6.png" alt="">
   <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
   <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>

</section>

<section class="slider_reviews">

<div class="sliderReviews_window">
 
 <div class="sliderReviews">

  <div class="reviews_item">
   <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="">
   <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
   <h4>Joshua Earle</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="reviews_item">
   <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="">
   <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
   <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="reviews_item">
   <img class="clearfix" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="">
   <p>“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.”</p>
   <h4>Jon Doe</h4>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>


</section>



</div>
```

Comment: Вы используете глобальную переменную `interval` для всех слайдеров?

Comment: судя по всему причина та же что и в прошлом вопросе - переменная глобальная. покажи где ты _объявляешь_ переменную interval

Comment: function nextSlide(){                                 
    interval = window.setInterval(animate, settings.sliderInterval);  //вот интервал // settings.sliderInterval --- берётся из settings 
  }

Comment: по идее interval каждому слайдеру должен задаваться отдельно